# Is the sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ divisible by $7$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, congruences, digits

> Is the sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ a multiple of $7$?

The sum of the digits of $3^{1000}$ can be computed using a computer. It is equal to $2142$, so the answer is positive.

**Is there a short proof that the sum of the digits of $3^{1000}$ is a multiple of $7$ without using a computer?**

Do you have any advice to solve this type of problem (without programming of course!)?

The results below are known:

- $3^{1000}$ has $478$ digits, and so the sum is at most $4302$ ($9\cdot478$).
- This sum is a multiple of $9$.
- The last four digits of $3^{1000}$ are $0001$.

---

Context: We are a group of 3 French people working on it since 2007. It's a little exercise I found in my high school book (printed in 2007) which is pretty complicated. The one who created this exercise doesn't know the answer.

This question was previously asked [on Math.SE (link)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433244/sum-of-digits-of-31000).

Comment: "We are a group of 3 french people working on it since 2007." OMG!

Comment: It looks as though this question was posted on MSE, and an answer there suggested asking here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2433244/sum-of-digits-of-31000

Comment: I personally think those who put this question on hold might consider to __retract__ the flag, since this question does not seem to be quite simple as at the first glance.

Comment: @Lwins.Gafield There is no flag, but a closing vote. On the other hand,  there are "reopening votes", which do not specifically concern those who closed the question (once the question is closed, the closing votes can't be retracted). Probably it requires some minimal reputation, I'm not sure how much. I guess the question will soon be reopened.

Comment: this Mathematica command outputs the remainder of the sum of digits of $3^n$, $n=1,2,\ldots 1000$ --- is there a pattern? Table[Mod[Total[IntegerDigits[3^n, 10]], 7], {n, 1, 1000}]

Comment: This is not a research-level question, voting to close. Either we fire up a computer and do it, or we're talking pedagogical mathematics.

Comment: Just so it's clear, the puny number discussed is 3^1000 = 1322070819480806636890455259752144365965422032752148167664920368226828597346704899540778313850608061963909777696872582355950954582100618911865342725257953674027620225198320803878014774228964841274390400117588618041128947815623094438061566173054086674490506178125480344405547054397038895817465368254916136220830268563778582290228416398307887896918556404084898937609373242171846359938695516765018940588109060426089671438864102814350385648747165832010614366132173102768902855220001, sum of digits is 2142 = 2 ⋅ 3² ⋅ 7 ⋅ 17. It fits in a comment.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I agree with your opinion that __this__ is not a research-level question. However, what would happen when we simply change $3^{1000}$ to $3^n$ or do something similar? Actually this question has been put on hold once.

Comment: Can't the criterion of divisibility by 7 that consists in truncating the considered integer before the unit digit and substracting it twice be used recursively ?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN I don't see how, since we are talking about the sum of digits being divisible by $7$, and we know nothing about the decimal expansion of this sum.

Comment: @AndrejBauer You didn't understand the question. It is the sum of digits of $3^n$ that we consider.

Comment: Yes, I keep typing the wrong formula into Mathematica, sorry! Ok, so if the question were "what's up with the sequence of sums of digits of powers of 3 modulo 7" that would plausibly be something that we could discuss. But that is *not* what *this* question is asking. The OP should at least edit the question.

Comment: Lwins, or anyone here, can you formulate a question, more precise than "what can be said?", on the sum of digits of $3^n$ reduced modulo $7$?

Comment: @Joël : We could ask, can the question "Digitsum$(3^n) \equiv 0 \pmod 7$?" be answered in time polynomial in $\log n$?

Comment: @coudy off-by-one error in the range of d, and hence the fraction should be 1/7

Comment: I am happy to see that this question was not closed. Even if question has elementary statement, it does not mean that it is easy. Besides computing sum of digits of $3^{1000}$ and checking that it is divisible by 7 is different thing than proving it without help of computer. If someone here have children at school then you know - nowadays children do not know multiplication table up to 100. They use smartphones for calculations. Mathematicians do the same :)

Comment: Seeing a computer proof of any facts about the sum of digits of this number is not satisfying or enlightening. Let's stop the complaining about the question and approach this problem like mathematicians, not like engineers with access to WolframAlpha.

Comment: The usual approach for mathematicians is to avoid most questions about decimal digits.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Could you define precisely what is a research-level question please ? I still have a lot of difficulty to comprehend this notion. What kind of question deserves to be called "research-level" and what kind of question is not "research-level". It's not a home work, and that does not seem to be trivial. I have voted for this question, even if it does not interest me.

Comment: I haven't down-voted, but the problem I have with the question, besides the trifle that $1000$ should be any $n$, is that I see no hint that it is more natural or accessible (even euristically) than a myriad similar ones (on sums of digits of $e$, $\sqrt{2}$, or of fibonacci numbers, or (mod $7$) behavior of A077468 and so on). I see no mention here of a  trick, tool or puzzling anomaly that might have been remotely helpful, even if on closer inspection it wasn't. Is massive up-voting because a first reading of the questions makes one think it's trivial, and then surprise or guilt follow?

Comment: I agree with Yaakov. I do not undertsand the massive upvoting.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher: no I will not define "what precisely is a research-level question", and I will not fall for such manipulative requests. You are quite welcome to "define" it yourself, but it would probably be more productive to read the relevant FAQ.

Comment: @coudy the first question of this exercise is : what is the last digit of $3^{1000}$ which is very easy. I still have the textbook and I didn't make any mistake...sorry

Comment: @coudy the name of the book is <Mathématiques Tome 2, 4eme année de l'enseignement supérieur "Math">

Comment: @Lezraf who is the editor and the author of the book? I assume it was edited in 2007.

Comment: @coudy Ministry of Education of Tunisia...One of the writers was my neighbour, he doesn't know the answer...yes the first version was in 2007

Comment: @coudy: to me this problem looks unassailable, but surely I may lack intuition or imagination and I agree it was fine to give it a try here. HOWEVER there has been no hint anywhere in this thread of any suggestion of any feature of multiplication by $3$, $9$ etc, that may even remotely connect with mod $7$ properties of decimal digits, or of any pattern in such digits, their sums and residuals, that does not seem hopelessly random... So 30 net upvotes + 17 favorites and counting, because case $n=1000$ was in an obscure high school book, perhaps as a programming exercise, seems over the top.

Comment: @coudy it's a normal exercise among other ones, the chapter name is "divisibility in Z" It doesn't have any thing to do with programming, I can send you a picture (it's in french)

Comment: Does anyone have a hint to know if the sum of $3^{1000}$ is divisible (or not divisible) by any number (2, 4 etc.) other than 3 or 9 ?

Comment: @Lezraf: $9$ is special because the "carry" operation changes a $10$ to $1$, which is the same thing mod $9$. Similarly, if you do sums of digits with alternating signs, $11$ is special because a carry changes 10 to -1. If you want an operator on the digits for which $7$ is special,  apply to the digits multipliers given by the powers of $3$ mod $7$: $1,3,2,6,4,5,\dots$, or  $1,3,2,-1,-3,-2,\dots$, since now a carry changes a $10$ to a $3$, which is no change mod $7$. I hope this clarifies why $9$ and only $9$ is special when you apply to the digits the multipliers $1,1,1...$.

Answer (score 11):

Middle digits of the numbers $3^n$ are unpredictable. At least it is too hard for current techniques to say anything about them. It means that the their sum  is unpredictable as well. Some good random number generators are based "digital" ideas.

If we take binary digits of $3^n$ then we immediately get generalization 
 of $(3/2)^n$-problem which is out of reach today.

This picture is taken from [a New Kind of Science](http://www.wolframscience.com/nks/):[image]

The pattern is very similar to "rule 30" picture from the same book:[image]

It is expected to have very good pseudorandom properties, see discussion at [A New Kind of Science: A 15-Year View.](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2017/05/a-new-kind-of-science-a-15-year-view/)

Comment: I feel this should've been a comment.

Comment: so you think we should close the topic?

Comment: @Lezraf I think yes. One can study this problem as a random number generator.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov Unfortunately I agree with you...

Answer (score 8):

Not an answer, but a series of considerations.

One expects not only the digit sum of 3^n to be a multiple of nine (for integral n greater than 1) but also for the string of digits (in the decimal representation of 3^n) to be somewhat normal in distribution, having roughly the same number of occurrences of each decimal digit.  For the given example, the actual digit sum is not far from the expected sum of 2151.

I have not observed the growth of the digit sum of powers of 3, but it should grow linearly with n, subject of course to being a multiple of 9 and not deviating far from the expected value.  (Using the posted example for interpolation, I expect the rate of growth of digit sum to average about 2.1 for every increment of n, or to increase by 9 about every 4 steps of n.) Because of this, I would expect 1/7th of the exponents n to yield a multiple of 7 for the digit sum of 3^n, and to occur in runs (or near runs) of length about 4. (So the digit sum may be a multiple of 7 for n=998 or n=1002 as well.) Indeed, if it weren't for the variation, I would expect the digit sums to be multiples of 7 near n=1006.

Gerhard "Not Ready For A Summary" Paseman, 2017.09.26.

Comment: Quite interesting. Computing  $ 4.5(\log_{10}3^{1000}-1) $  I get  $ 2142.5456... $ so perhaps rounding the decimal log to the greatest even integer below it would do the job.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: certainly not! A plot of sum_of_digits($3^n$) shows a lot of random jitter of increasing amplitude (but decreasing amplitude if one plots log(sum_of_digits) instead). I think this question is much like asking whether there is a shortcut to check if the sum of the first $n$ digits of, say, $\pi$ is a multiple of $7$ - but with a misleading number theory flavor that makes one think it possible.

Comment: I mean that n should be large enough to make the normality hypothesis that Gerhard mentions hold. For rather small values of n, it is more convenient to use a computer.

Comment: As Gerhard suspects, for $2\le n\le 10000$, this is the unremarkable frequency of the values of the sum of digits (mod $7$): 0 1374, 1 1467, 2 1408, 3 1418, 4 1466, 5 1458, 6 1408.

Comment: Also, for $n \le 20000$ (working with simple "gawk -M" commands) I see for each of the 7 possibilities (mod $7$) runs of 4 or 5 consecutive equal values, as well as gaps of at least 50 in their occurrence.

Comment: You use gawk -M too? Gerhard "Prototyping Near To My Heart" Paseman, 2017.09.26.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Is the jitter of size $\sqrt{8.25 \log_{10} (3^n)}$, as would be predicted by the random model if I calculated correctly?

Comment: @WillSawin. Yes, for $n\le 20000$ the observed sdev (off the expected $4.5\log_{10}(3^n)$) is $1.00452$ times the value you gave, and the small local fluctuations within the interval show no trends or other remarkable features.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Even if one expects to have normality, note that the sum of $n$ uniformly distributed digits still has SD $\approx\sqrt{n}$, so much too large for approximations of the sort you're suggesting to be consistent to within the subunit ranges needed for it to do any good.

Comment: A distribution of the last digits of first 100 numbers  for which sum of digits of 3^n is divisible by 7 shows some bias.